# How to solve ${d^3f(x) \over dx^3} +\big( e^{2x} - {4 \over 3} \big) {df(x) \over dx} +{1 \over 3}\big( e^{2x} + {16 \over 9} \big) f(x) = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the process of solving a problem, I came across the following ordinary differential equation:

$$ {d^3f(x) \over dx^3} +
   \Bigg( e^{2x} - {4 \over 3} \Bigg) {df(x) \over dx} +
   {1 \over 3}\Bigg( e^{2x} + {16 \over 9} \Bigg) f(x) = 0 $$

Unfortunately, the methods I know for solving differential equations with functional coefficients are not applicable in this case. So my question is, how can I solve this equation? Note that the initial conditions are:

$$ f(0)=C_1 $$
$$ {df(0) \over dx}=C_2 $$
$$ {d^2f(0) \over dx^2}=C_3 $$

Comment: Just $a$ constant definitely does not work because there is no way for the $e^{4x}$ terms to cancel.

Comment: Maple does not solve it in closed form.  So I'm guessing there is no solution in terms of the commonly-used special functions.

Comment: WA gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=f%27%27%27%28x%29%2B%28e%5E%282x%29-4%2F3%29f%27%28x%29%2B%28%28e%5E%282x%29%2B16%2F9%29%2F3%29f%28x%29%3D0).